# How to get access token from instance of google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials object?

Tags: google-oauth, credentials, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

How to get access token from instance of `google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials` object?

I need to access an google api endpoint which needs authorisation. For that, I need to provide an access token in request headers.

How to get the access token from this instance of Credentials object?

In case of `oauth2client.service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials` object, they provide a method to fetch an access token(called `get_access_token()`), but I could not find any such method for `google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials`. Any help would be appreciated.

I want to do this inside python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure why you need one as you should be building a service object for which ever api it is you are trying to access. However the following should give you the access token.

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES) 

credentials.access_token
```