# Get access token from google.oauth2.Credentials

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, tensorflow-serving

Currently, I am building the async frontend to my TF2 model. Now it works as two services, 1st service is a twisted service, and 2nd service is a TensorFlow serving.

The async web client is being used to query the model asynchronously. For practical reasons, I've deployed the model into the GCP AI Platform, and I can get data from it using the python code from examples, and it is okay.

But the thing is that the Google API client is synchronous, and I would like to use the asynchronous client. Since, AFAIK, there are no actively supported async clients for GCP, I tried to get straightforward and use REST. The model input is the same on TensorFlow serving (GCP AI Platform uses TensorFlow serving internally, I believe).

To perform the async call, I need to have:

1. Model URL. (I have it)
2. Input data. (I also have it)
3. Access token.

I saw some examples that are:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    '/path/to/key.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
```

But the issue is that `credential.token` is `None`, so I can't use it.

So I have a question: how could I get the access token to use in the rest request then?

Or maybe there is another but better way of doing that?

I already saw the following question: [How to get access token from instance of google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67102599/how-to-get-access-token-from-instance-of-google-oauth2-service-account-credentia)
but I am think that it is slightly irrelevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code sets up the data structures for managing credentials (OAuth tokens) from a service account. No tokens are requested at this point.

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    '/path/to/key.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
```

Tokens are not requested from the Google auth server until required. There are several reasons: a) network calls take time - a significant amount of time for network failures; b) tokens expire; c) tokens are cached until they (almost) expire.

To generate a token, call the **refresh()** method:

```
import google.auth.transport.requests
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request)
```

**credential.token** will now contain an OAuth Access Token else an exception will be thrown (network error, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your response, just one minor question: is that possible to get the credentials without constructing the request object?

Comment: @justnoxx - Yes, you can request OAuth tokens without using the SDK. I wrote an article showing the process of creating a Signed JWT and exchanging that for tokens in Python. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: Do you know what to do if you prefer to store the key.json info as a variable instead?  I'd much rather store it as an environment variable that I can retrieve in my settings.py file than hard-code it into a file in the .ebextensions folder and commit it to the git repo, as the latter method seems much more insecure.

Comment: Nvm - found the answer in their git repo.  There is a Credentials.from_service_account_info method that can be used for this purpose.  https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/main/google/oauth2/service_account.py